# How can I use launchctl to send a signal to a service?

Tags: command-line, security, services

As you can already see in the text below and screenshot of the terminal, whenever I try to send a signal to a service I have given `Not privileged to signal service.` and `Could not kickstart service "com.apple.accessibility.heard": 1: Operation not permitted.`

```
~ % launchctl kickstart -k gui/$(id -u)/com.apple.accessibility.heard    
Could not kickstart service "com.apple.accessibility.heard": 1: Operation not permitted
~ % sudo launchctl kickstart -k gui/$(id -u)/com.apple.accessibility.heard
Could not kickstart service "com.apple.accessibility.heard": 1: Operation not permitted
~ % launchctl kill SIGHUP gui/$(id -u)/com.apple.accessibility.heard     
Not privileged to signal service.
~ % sudo launchctl kill SIGHUP gui/$(id -u)/com.apple.accessibility.heard
Not privileged to signal service.
```

[image]

Does anybody have an idea to overcome this issue?

Edit:

Just to be clear, I am trying to start Background Sounds feature from terminal

```
defaults write com.apple.ComfortSounds comfortSoundsEnabled -bool YES
defaults write com.apple.ComfortSounds lastEnablementTimestamp $(date +%s)
launchctl kill SIGHUP gui/$(id -u)/com.apple.accessibility.heard
```

Second Edit:

I have solved my problem using the following commands, but still wondering **why cannot send signals to services?**

```
defaults write com.apple.ComfortSounds comfortSoundsEnabled -bool YES
killall heard
launchctl kickstart gui/$(id -u)/com.apple.accessibility.heard
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by restarting this service? Maybe start with stating that and someone might know a better way.

Comment: Also *Operation not Permitted* ≠ *Full Disk Access* not enabled.  It could be a UNIX permission issue instead

Comment: i have edited my question which now includes my intent also.

Comment: Is the service running at the time you try to send a signal? If yes, what is the output of `ps aux|grep NAME`

Comment: guru               529   0.0  0.2 410431392  38560   ??  S     5:19AM   0:37.74 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HearingCore.framework/heard